# MVC - localise [Display] attribute, but not just Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resources, data-annotations

I've been trying to localise my ASP.NET MVC website and I decided to make resource files for storing my strings. I have a model with annotations made like this:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your e-mail address")]
    [Display(Name = "E-mail address:", Prompt = "somename@mail.com")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

This is my new resource file:

```
Contact.resx
EmailName     E-mail address:
EmailPrompt   sample@mail.com
EmailReq      Please enter your e-mail address
```

I want to use the resource file and get the strings out of it. I managed to make it work for [Required] and [Display] but just for the name:

```
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Contact), ErrorMessageResourceName = "EmailReq")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Contact), Name = "EmailName")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

But what about Prompt? If I add Prompt = "EmailPrompt" it just saves "EmailPrompt" as the string, not "sample@mail.com". How do I solve this?

Comment: Also take a look at this one: http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2012/09/04/localization-in-asp.net-mvc-ndash-upgraded.aspx

Comment: I already read those articles, but the problem is in the [Display] annotation - this MSDN article says that if ResourceType != null, the Prompt string should refer to the key name in the resource file - and it doesn't - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.resourcetype.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem, and it's been a mistake in another piece of code. I was getting the Prompt value through reflection. It's a big difference in getting the value through the public field Prompt and GetPrompt() method:

```
DisplayAttribute attr = GetTheAttribute();
string firstVal = attr.Prompt;
string secondVal = attr.GetPrompt();
```

The firstVal contains the name of the key for which to look in the resource file; the actual value of the resource is retrieved with GetPrompt(), as in secondVal.